# Open a VBA Multi Tab Form in Excel to a specific tab

Tags: forms, vba, excel, multipage

I'm confident this is going to be a very easy answer for anyone with VBA knowledge (which I don't have).  I have a form built for Excel in VBA.  It's a multitab form and I want to have the form consistently open on the first tab when the "Open Form X" button is clicked in Excel.  Let's call the form "Form1" and the tab "IDTab"

I have tried the following code but neither has worked:

```
Private Sub GetFormButton_Click() 
    Form1.Show With MultiPage1 Value = 0 
End Sub
```

AND

```
Private Sub BackToExclu_Click() 

 With MultiPage1 
    .Value = (.Value - 1) Mod (.Pages.Count) 
 End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: first, welcome to SO. Second, please show us your coding efforts to accomplish this on your own. This is not a "code-writing" service, but rather a forum to get solutions to existing code that does not work. For more information see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Third, have you even tried searching on google for a solution?

Comment: I have tried both     `Private Sub GetFormButton_Click()
Form1.Show


With MultiPage1
Value = 0`    and      `Private Sub BackToExclu_Click()
With MultiPage1
    .Value = (.Value - 1) Mod (.Pages.Count)
End With
End Sub`  and neither seemed to work.    I have tried Googling but I wasn't sure exactly if what I was asking was correct and a lot of the results I got back were to do with Access 2003, didn't know if VBA worked the same in both modules (and the language & syntax seemed a bit different)

Comment: thanks. I put your code in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

You were very close, actually :)

If you place the code into the `Initiliaze Event` within the userform itself, it will always display the first page of the multi-page control any time the form is loaded.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

     Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0

End Sub
```

To place this code into the UserForm Module, right click on the `UserForm` object in the VBE and click `View Code`.

Then your button click code would just be:

```
Private Sub GetFormButton_Click() 
    Form1.Show 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Open y

1. open your excel workbook
2. find your form
3. right click the name of the form
4. select "show program code"

In the programcode for the form enter the code below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  MultiPage1.Pages("IDTab").Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Mind you: MultiPage1 might be called differently in your form. MultiPage1 is the default name of the container holding the tabbed pages in my excel workbook. In the properety window you can find the actual name of that container.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Looks like so far, it's working.  I'll save and reopen a few times to make sure it's functioning as it should.